# FFmpeg: format error when trying to use hardware scale_npp filter

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, screen-capture, hardware-acceleration

I have CUDA installed on Ubuntu 22.04LTS with NVidia Geforce graphic card. I am currently trying to capture the full desktop by running this command

```bash
ffmpeg -y -hide_banner \
  -hwaccel cuda \
  -f x11grab \
  -framerate 25 \
  -video_size 3840x2160 \
  -i :1.0+0,0 \
  -vf "scale_npp=1920:-1" \
  -c:v hevc_nvenc -cq:v 21 -preset slow \
  output.mp4
```

The `scale_npp` filter causes the following error:

```
Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'
[vf#0:0 @ 0x561418cffe00] Error reinitializing filters!
[vf#0:0 @ 0x561418cffe00] Task finished with error code: -38 (Function not implemented)
[vf#0:0 @ 0x561418cffe00] Terminating thread with return code -38 (Function not implemented)
[vost#0:0/hevc_nvenc @ 0x561418ce2840] Could not open encoder before EOF
[vost#0:0/hevc_nvenc @ 0x561418ce2840] Task finished with error code: -22 (Invalid argument)
[vost#0:0/hevc_nvenc @ 0x561418ce2840] Terminating thread with return code -22 (Invalid argument)
[out#0/mp4 @ 0x561418ce0c00] Nothing was written into output file, because at least one of its streams received no packets.
```

I don't know if everything is working because of the error `Function not implemented`.

In general, I'd like to make sure everything is done on my GPU and then the final result sent to the ouput file.

Below are a few outputs from a system:

- `ffmpeg -hide_banner -h encoder=hevc_nvenc`

```
Encoder hevc_nvenc [NVIDIA NVENC hevc encoder]:
    General capabilities: dr1 delay hardware 
    Threading capabilities: none
    Supported hardware devices: cuda cuda 
    Supported pixel formats: yuv420p nv12 p010le yuv444p p016le yuv444p16le bgr0 bgra rgb0 rgba x2rgb10le x2bgr10le gbrp gbrp16le cuda
```

- `ffmpeg -hide_banner -h filter=scale_npp`

```
Filter scale_npp
  NVIDIA Performance Primitives video scaling and format conversion
    Inputs:
       #0: default (video)
    Outputs:
       #0: default (video)
```

Comment: The core error is: “Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter 'graph 0 input from stream 0:0' and the filter 'auto_scale_0'”

Comment: @Giacomo1968 thanks for indication where the error is but that didn't help me much. If I understand, `x11grab` provides source frames in unsupported format and I'd need to convert it to something `scale_npp` accepts, e.g. `yuv420p`. However, no matter what I try, I always get the same error. Things I tried:  `format=pix_fmt=yuv420p,scale_npp=1920:-1` or a format within `scale_npp`, that is `scale_npp=1920:-1:format=yuv420p` and get exactly the same error. I've not clue where the conversion should be.

Comment: That’s why “thanks for indication where the error is but that didn't help me much.” it is a comment. It seems that `scale_npp` need to be converted to an intermediary. Or another idea is HEVC can choke on non-even numbers. So when you set `scale_npp=1920:-1` it is essentially saying it should automatically calculate height. What if that is set explicitly to `scale_npp=1920:1080`? Could be an auto-height is being set to `1079` or `1081` and that cause it to fail but explicitly setting it to `1080` might solve it?

Comment: @Giacomo1968 There doesn't seem to be any difference. It reports the same error: `Impossible to convert between the formats supported by the filter ...`. I can remove the filter and it's working fine. It's just I didn't want to record in 4K if I wouldn't meed to.

Comment: Try adding `hwupload_cuda` before `scale_npp` (and remove `-hwaccel cuda`): `ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -f x11grab -framerate 25 -video_size 3840x2160 -i :1.0+0,0 -vf "hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=1920:-1" -c:v hevc_nvenc -cq:v 21 -preset slow output.mp4`. Maybe we also have to add `format=yuv444p`: `ffmpeg -y -hide_banner -f x11grab -framerate 25 -video_size 3840x2160 -i :1.0+0,0 -vf "format=yuv444p,hwupload_cuda,scale_npp=1920:-1" -c:v hevc_nvenc -cq:v 21 -preset slow output.mp4`

Comment: @Rotem The second command works with no more errors related to impossible converting. However, `format=yuv444p` creates gibberish on a output video. I changed a filter to `format=yuv420p` and everything seems to be OK. If you have an idea why, at least why `-hwaccel cuda` didn't work and we have to use `hwupload_cuda` instead, please do add an answer. It will be useful because that is not well explained in any source I tried. This would be very useful. And I'd vote up and accept your answer.

Comment: @Rotem I also tried `libx264` to see if there is any difference between how CPU and GPU is involved comparing to hardware accelerating. With `hevc_nvenc`, GPU seems to take over, although CPU is still slightly involved I guess due to `x11grab`. Thanks.

Comment: `x11grab` grabs the desktop to the system memory, and not to the GPU "device" memory. The desktop pixel format is raw bgra format. `-hwaccel cuda` is used for hardware accelerated video decoding, and there is nothing to decode since the input format is raw video (`-hwaccel cuda` has no effect). Due to implementation reasons, we can't upload the `bgra` format to the GPU, and we have to convert it to `yuv420p`. The pixel format conversion is performed in the CPU. The CPU loaded due to the grabbing, and the pixel format conversion. Note: HEVC applies H.265 codec and x264 applies H.264 codec.